# Regex: extracting a value in a string <Name_id = bob>?

Tags: java, regex

What would be the correct regular expression (that I can use in Java) if I want to extract a value from the string below?

```
<Name_id = bob>
```

I know that `\<(.*?)\>` will extract everything between the angle brackets but I only need to extract "bob".

The only part of the string that will change will be "bob". I also want to make sure that if someone enters `=bob` as the Name_id, the string that pulled out will be just that and doesn't mess up the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the characters you want.

```
"<Name_id\\s+=\\s+([^>]+)>"
```

OR

```
"<Name_id\\s+=\\s+([\w]+)>"
```

And then print group index 1 at the last. `\s+` matches one or more space characters and `\w+` matches one or more word characters.

```
String i = "<Name_id = bob>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<Name_id\\s+=\\s+([^>]+)>").matcher(i);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
bob
```